# Microphone should work and yet it doesn't?

Tags: audio

Testing it through windows and realtek with the "listen to voice" option on makes it work perfectly and I can hear my own voice. However when talking through it in another software such as discord and skype, no sound can be picked up because its apparently too quiet. Drivers are up to date and the sound is maxed out from the "Sound device" options.

Answer (score 0):

I've used discord in the past, not so much recently, but I remember having to change my input device so it was using the right device for audio in. Even with other programs like Audacity or Adobe Audition, I've always had to select the audio in device. So check in the settings for the voice channel and see if it's using the right device. Might even try and make sure the microphone is set as the default communication device.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Your signal path is interrupted somewhere.

Trace every link in the chain, being clear that it is passing the signal.